# Test REST APIs on a real server (without localhost )

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, postman

I have a @RestController class in my Spring Boot app.I tested my api's with postman on localhost and everything seems to be ok.
So now I want to test it from another computer.
Is there a server/technology  which will allow me to test my api's without localhost.
So instead of:
http://localhost:8095/api/all-users
I have:
http://magicServer.com/api/all-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this too on your local machine with an entry in the `hosts` file of your OS.

```
127.0.0.1 magicServer.com
```

And listen on port 80.

server.port = 80

If not, of course you need a server on the internet and a domain of your ownership, than you can point the Internet DNS to your server.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer Peter, what do you think, can I do it with the help of Mock servers, like Mockapi or Mock Server of Postman?

Comment: Take an Oracle Free Tier root vserver and deploy what you want https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/ .